# Bundle Identifier issue when using WatchKit

Tags: xcode, watchkit, code-signing

Ok so I have an app which has been on the store since May 2009. It was my very first app and I didn't really understand App ID's and Bundle identifiers at the time so I just messed about until it worked. The app ID ended up being 46****7GHZ. (some characters blanked out for security). and that's it.

The app is now on version 2.3 and was last updated in 2013. I still have all of my builds and having gone back through them to check, iTunes Connect has been happy with me simply setting the bundle ID as 46****7GHZ. Since then every other app I've made has used com.something.appname.

Now however I'm facing real problems. I've added WatchKit to the app and it isn't playing ball.

I've turned off all automatic code signing and generated 3 separate app ID's and provisioning profiles for the App, the WatchKit and the extension.

This has taken care of all errors but one. Invalid CFBundleIdentifier value 46****7GHZ.watchkit of watch application 'App.app/Watch/Watch App.app' does not properly extend the CFBundleIdentifier value '46****7GHZ.' of it's containing iOS application.

So at present my bundle ID's are like so:

- App: 46****7GHZ.
- WatchApp 46****7GHZ.watchkit
- Extension 46****7GHZ.watchkit.extension
- Companion app ID: 46****7GHZ.
- WKAppBundle ID: 46****7GHZ.watchkit

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel pretty stupid now as I figured it out.

My bundle ID 467***GHZ. the period is actually included as part of the name.

So 467SNW7GHZ.watchkitapp needed to become 467SNW7GHZ..watchkitapp

It doesn't look right but it works and the build is now sitting happily waiting for review.